# Online Learning with SGD using Occasional Updates

Tags: optimization, machine-learning, signal-processing

I am working on an online machine learning scheme, where SGD is utilized. However, in my case, calculation of the gradient is rather costy & the adjacent input samples are very similar. Therefore, I do not want to measure gradient and make updates for every new sample, but update occasionally when a significant change in the input is present. I want this update scheme to be mathematically justifable since this one will be in my masters thesis.

My questions are:
1) Does this make sense or are there better strategies?
2) What might be a good measure of 'sufficient change in inputs'? (I use time series)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you try to change size of batches? Do not forget shuffle your data before training.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Anton. Actually, I have a streaming data and want to find a smart way to obtain sizes of mini-batches.